# Understanding the access path from ApiEvent

Tags: connected-apps, oauth, event-monitoring

Hello Salesforce Community,

I am facing a challenge in correlating ApiEvent records with OAuthToken, particularly for connected apps that haven't been installed in our Salesforce org. While I can see ApiEvent records for installed connected apps with a non-null ConnectedAppId, I am unable to do the same for those that are authorized but not installed.

For example, this is a record from ApiEvent that was triggered by Salesforce CLI before being installed as a package:
[image: Record before package installation]

And here is the record after the installation:
[image: Record after package installation]

Is there a way to retrieve this information somehow?

Comment: The rest of the fields are _usually_ (but not _always_) enough to compose a heuristic rule (report/analytics) that identifies the source. `Application` field is often a significant clue if the access is via oAuth with the connected app hosted elsewhere.